# Excel add serial number column based on another column grouped

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

We have thousands of rows of data in the following format

```
| Name       | Born On     |
|:-----------|------------:|
| Tom        |      Jul 15 |
| Harry      |      Jul 15 |
| Katy       |       Oct 2 |
| Britney    |       Oct 2 |
| Miranda    |       Oct 2 |
| Victoria   |       Oct 2 |
| John       |      Sep 30 |
| Warren     |      Sep 30 |
| George     |      Sep 30 |
```

I would like to add a serial number based on the "Born On" column as follows

```
| Name       | Born On     | Serial Number
|:-----------|------------:|--------------:|
| Tom        |      Jul 15 |  1
| Harry      |      Jul 15 |  2
| Katy       |       Oct 2 |  1
| Britney    |       Oct 2 |  2
| Miranda    |       Oct 2 |  3
| Victoria   |       Oct 2 |  4
| John       |      Sep 30 |  1
| Warren     |      Sep 30 |  2
| George     |      Sep 30 |  3
```

The "serial number" needs to be grouped by "born on" date.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Is the column 'Born on' sorted? Also, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Several questions: Does the "Born On" column contain Excel dates or are they strings? If dates, are they sorted by date or by month value?   ALso, if dates, do they contain more than one year of dates?

Comment: Yes, the "Born On" column is sorted and stored in string format.

Comment: @user374760 Since column B is sorted, you can easily use `=IF(B2=B1,C1+1,1)` in cell C2 and drag down for a faster process.

Comment: Jerry: We have 150,000 rows of data and using this solution took only a second or two to process. Worked perfect. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the serial numbers start in cell C2 and the Born on cells start in B2, then use this formula in cell C2 and copy down:

```
=COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)
```

Comment: awesome. saves a lot of time :)